# Sorting of client side with page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I done sorting of gridview. It worked perfectly, but I refresh the page every 60sec. So when I sort Asc to Desc. The page stay into Desc page, but after the page refresh, the grid goes to Asc direction. But I want to stay into last sorting direction, when page load. Is it possible? My sorting code is:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $.tablesorter.addParser({
            id: 'amount',
            is: function (s) {
                return false;
            },
            format: function (s) {
                return s; 
            },
            type: 'numeric'
        });

        $.tablesorter.addParser({
            id: "commaDigit",
            is: function (s) {
                return false;
            },
            format: function (s) {
                return s;
            },
            type: "numeric"
        });

        $.tablesorter.addParser({
            id: 'balance',
            is: function (s) {
                return false;
            },
            format: function (s) {
                return s;
            },
            type: 'numeric'
        });


        $(function () {
            $("#<%=gvCustomerTranInfo.ClientID%>").tablesorter({
                headers: {
                    1: {
                        sorter: 'commaDigit'
                    },
                    3: {
                        sorter: 'amount'
                    }
                }
            });
            SetDefaultSortOrder();
        });
    });



    function Sort(cell, sortOrder) {
        var sorting = [[cell.cellIndex, sortOrder]];
        $("#<%=gvCustomerTranInfo.ClientID%>").trigger("sorton", [sorting]);
        if (sortOrder == 0) {
            sortOrder = 1;
            cell.className = "sortDesc";
        }
        else {
            sortOrder = 0;
            cell.className = "sortAsc";
        }
        cell.setAttribute("onclick", "Sort(this, " + sortOrder + ")");
        cell.onclick = function () { Sort(this, sortOrder); };
        document.getElementById("<%=pnlCustomerTranInfo.ClientID %>").scrollTop = 0;
    }

    function SetDefaultSortOrder() {
        var gvHeader = document.getElementById("dummyTranHeader");
        if (gvHeader != null) {
            var headers = gvHeader.getElementsByTagName("TH");
            for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
               headers[i].setAttribute("onclick", "Sort(this, 1)");
                headers[i].onclick = function () { Sort(this, 1); };
                headers[i].className = "sortDesc";
            }
        }
    }
```

I do sorting code in client side using asp.net

Comment: Do you refresh whole page or only an area?

Answer (score 0):

If doing refresh it goes back to server-side, you'll need to give the page a hint as to what order the sorting is to be in.

You can add a querystring parameter, so it stays on refresh.

Comment: For refresh i done code:  $(document).ready(function () {
            window.setInterval(yourfunction, 10000);
        });
        function yourfunction() { window.location = "Customer.aspx"; }

Comment: it is possible or not?pls replay me